# Java byte type in enum constructor

Tags: java, enums

```
public enum Rank {
    TEN("Ten",1),
    NINE("Nine",2),
    EIGHT("Eight",0),
    SEVEN("Seven",0);


    private final String name;
    private final int point;

    /*
     * @param rank should be byte
     */
    private Rank(String name,int point)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.point=point;
    }
```

How to replace int to byte in point. One way i can think of is using `TEN("Ten",Byte.parseByte("1"));`

Is there any better or/and shorter approach?

Comment: Why don;t you cast it `(byte)1` ?

Comment: Why do you want it to be a `byte`, the object won't be any smaller and the value won't be any different.

Comment: @PeterLawrey how? Byte should assign lesser memory. is not it?

Comment: @fallenAngel Not that saving 3 bytes is going to matter, but Objects are allocated on 8 byte boundaries.  The size of the object will be the same whether you use byte, char, short, int or float as the reference is highly likely to be 32-bit even on 64-bit JVMs.  Note if the reference is actually 64-bit, it could be a a `long` and the size would be unchanged.

Comment: @fallenAngel 3 bytes costs about one millionth of a cent.  The time it takes to press one key on minimum wage is worth more than 1000x this. i.e. by typing one less letter by using `int` you will save much, more in your time.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am not going to need more than one byte for that field. So why to use more than that what i am not going to use.That's the reason i choosen byte. I have not any performance concern on this but i would like to clear out the concept. I dont understand if byte does not do anything good why to have a different data type?

Comment: Bytes can be useful when you have arbitrarily large numbers of them, say, thousands or millions of bytes. When you have exactly four bytes, there's just no point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just `cast` to a `byte`, like so:

```
public enum Rank {
    TEN("Ten", (byte)1),
    NINE("Nine", (byte)2),
    EIGHT("Eight", (byte)0),
    SEVEN("Seven", (byte)0);


    private final String name;
    private final byte point;

    private Rank(String name, byte point)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.point = point;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

A shorter approach is casting.

```
TEN("Ten", (byte) 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a style suggestion, move the cast in the constructor, so it looks cleaner:

```
public enum Rank {
    TEN("Ten", 1),
    NINE("Nine", 2),
    EIGHT("Eight", 0),
    SEVEN("Seven", 0);


    private final String name;
    private final byte point;

    private Rank(String name, int point)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.point = (byte)point;
    }
```